# sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = near "file_theme_column": syntax error

Tags: android, database, sqlite

this is my code to create  database table

```
String sqlQueryToCreateFileTable = "create table if not exists " + TABLE_FILE + " ( " + BaseColumns._ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " 
+ COLUMN_NAME_FILE_NAME + " text not null, "
+ COLUMN_NAME_FILE_CATEGORY+ " integer not null , FOREIGN KEY ("+COLUMN_NAME_FILE_CATEGORY+") REFERENCES "+TABLE_CATEGORY+" ("+BaseColumns._ID+"), " 
+ COLLUMN_NAME_FILE_THEME+ " integer not null , FOREIGN KEY ("+COLLUMN_NAME_FILE_THEME+") REFERENCES "+TABLE_THEME+" ("+BaseColumns._ID+"), " 
+ COLLUMN_NAME_FILE_DATE_CREATING+ " integer not null , FOREIGN KEY ("+COLLUMN_NAME_FILE_DATE_CREATING +") REFERENCES "+TABLE_DATE+" ("+BaseColumns._ID+"), " 
+ COLLUMN_NAME_FILE_CLOUD + " text default null,"
+ COLLUMN_NAME_FILE_DATE_UPLOADING + " text default null);";

db.execSQL(sqlQueryToCreateFileTable);
```

but I have that in the logcat

```
06-15 18:24:09.177: I/Process(9075): Sending signal. PID: 9075 SIG: 9
06-15 18:31:01.428: I/Database(10559): sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = near "file_theme_column": syntax error
06-15 18:31:01.428: E/Database(10559): Failure 1 (near "file_theme_column": syntax error) on 0x5882f8 when preparing 'create table if not exists file_table ( _id integer primary key autoincrement, file_name_column text not null, file_category_column integer not null , FOREIGN KEY (file_category_column) REFERENCES category_table (_id), file_theme_column integer not null , FOREIGN KEY (file_theme_column) REFERENCES theme_table (_id), file_date_creating_column integer not null , FOREIGN KEY (file_date_creating_column) REFERENCES date_table (_id), file_cloud_column text default null,file_date_upload_column text default null);'.
06-15 18:31:01.468: D/AndroidRuntime(10559): Shutting down VM
06-15 18:31:01.468: W/dalvikvm(10559): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
06-15 18:31:01.488: E/AndroidRuntime(10559): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-15 18:31:01.488: E/AndroidRuntime(10559): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "file_theme_column": syntax error: create table if not exists file_table ( _id integer primary key autoincrement, file_name_column text not null, file_category_column integer not null , FOREIGN KEY (file_category_column) REFERENCES category_table (_id), file_theme_column integer not null , FOREIGN KEY (file_theme_column) REFERENCES theme_table (_id), file_date_creating_column integer not null , FOREIGN KEY (file_date_creating_column) REFERENCES date_table (_id), file_cloud_column text default null,file_date_upload_column text default null);
06-15 18:31:01.488: E/AndroidRuntime(10559):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.native_execSQL(Native Method)
06-15 18:31:01.488: E/AndroidRuntime(10559):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1763)
06-15 18:31:01.488: E/AndroidRuntime(10559):    at com.app.pfe.AndroidOpenDbHelper.onCreate(AndroidOpenDbHelper.java:95)
06-15 18:31:01.488: E/AndroidRuntime(10559):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:126)
 how can I fix this error?
```

Comment: Just searched your code to create database table and it does not contain "file_theme_column"?  are you sure you have posted the actual create statement that is causing error?

Comment: the error is caused when creating table_file , I will edit my post to contain the DBhelper class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like pawelzieba said, you should try reformatting to

```
create table if not exists file_table ( 
    _id integer primary key autoincrement, 
    file_name_column text not null, 
    file_category_column integer not null, 
    file_theme_column integer not null, 
    file_date_creating_column integer not null, 
    file_cloud_column text default null,
    file_date_upload_column text default null,
    FOREIGN KEY (file_category_column) REFERENCES category_table (_id), 
    FOREIGN KEY (file_theme_column) REFERENCES theme_table (_id), 
    FOREIGN KEY (file_date_creating_column) REFERENCES date_table (_id)
);
```

Comment: thanks you to saved me, if I could I accept the both answer you and pawelazeiba , it is very helpful

Answer (score 4):

Table constraints should go to the end:

http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html